# Download file from response header Content-Disposition without a file name - Python

Tags: python, json, scrapy, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** information from youtube. Where youtube uses infinite scroll, after every pull ajax calls up for more data. I am using scrapy on python, while i request to this url(with continuation token)

`'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tamil&ctoken=xyz&continuation=xyz'` i received the status 200 with the following header.

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
cache-control: no-cache
content-disposition: attachment
expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-encoding: br
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-spf-response-type: multipart
x-content-type-options: nosniff
date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 11:59:25 GMT
server: YouTube Frontend Proxy
x-xss-protection: 0
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

I just need to download the response json. i can view the response in Chrome and firefox inspector.

here is what i tried.

```
links = https://www.youtube.com/result?xyxxxx
ctoken = xyxxxxxxxx
ajax_url = "{links}&ctoken={ctoken}&continuation={ctoken}".format(ctoken=ctoken, links=links)
new_data = requests.get(ajax_url).json()
```

I am getting error on this.

What i am interested is, can i download the response as JSON file for further usage, by making use of content-disposition: attachment. If i need to download the response how can i implement.

Comment: Use “Copy as cURL” from the network inspector of your web browser and then use https://michael-shub.github.io/curl2scrapy/ to build an equivalent request.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.json');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

where header should the response of ajax call.

Comment: How can i add this header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.json'); to the response. The received response is 'Content-Disposition: attachment; I need to save the response json file